# Did I miss anything with this $http.jsonp in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I know this question has been asked several times, but I'm not understanding if I missed anything or it's just a server thing.
I need to show you my code for checking please:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('c4s', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);

app.controller('curiousCtrl', function($http, $scope){
    $scope.stories = [];

    $http.jsonp('http://curious4science.com/?json=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')

        .success(function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response.data.children, function(child){
                console.log(response);
                $scope.stories.push(child.data);
            });
        });
});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $stateProvider

      // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
        .state('tab', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
}());
```

And I'm getting this error:

TypeError: response.data is undefined

First, I tried $http.get(....) but I got the error that cross domain thing is not allowed. Then I tried jsop.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the URL you are making the request return JSONP data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sucess() callback doesn't take the http response as argument. It takes the response data, then the status, then the headers, then the config.

So the code should be

```
$http.jsonp('http://curious4science.com/?json=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data) {
        angular.forEach(data.children, function(child){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.stories.push(child.data);
        });
    });
```

(assuming the returned JSON has a `children` field which is an array, and that each child has a data field, of course).

Comment: I tried it, and no error received nor data, so I added console.log(data) and I could see the object with the data, so Tons of  Thanks to you!
but do you have any idea why the data is not showing?
in html file:

<div ng-repeat="story in stories">
            {{story.title}}
        </div>

Comment: Because there is no `children` field in the returned JSON. The structure of the object you actually get is not the one you think it is. Just paste the URL in your browser address bar, and see what the returned JSON looks like.

Comment: JB Nizet, you rock!! it works! it's been 4 days and I'm knocking my head on the wall! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Knocking you head on the wall won't make things go faster, I fear :)

Comment: Yes you're right, but not because I want to go faster, there were things that I did not understand, now with your help here, things were clear.